# values for placeholders in POM file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a project and it has aPOM file, I have the below entry in it.

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <url>${repo.deploy}</url>   
</repository>
```

Values for the placeholders are not available in POM file. Where should these things be configured? In settings.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 1):

They should be available in pom.xml file, project.artifactId is in pom file you should find:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.expample</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <name>hub.js</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    ....

</project>
```

In the example, the value of ${project.artifactId} is "example".

The case of ${repo.deploy} is different, I think it not belong to the pom extructure, so you should declare a property in the pom (it could be as part of a profile) or in the setting.xml